# Bootstrap modal not showing properly in site

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I recently started fiddling around with Bootstrap modals on a site I'm working on, and they won't seem to show up at all on my site. I read some of the other posts and tried what they said to try, and none of it worked. [Here's the site itself](http://legalstudiesacademy.com/test/) The only active modal is the launch demo modal button, so try that one

Here's my `<head>` portion:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico">

    <title>#OnlyAtLSA</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script>
          $(function(){
             $("#button").click(function(){
                $('#modal').modal('show');
             });
          });
        </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assets/css/cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="/assets/css/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.4.0/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>
```

and here is my trigger button:
`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xlarge" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mission">
Launch demo modal
</button>`

And here is my modal itself:

```html
 <!-- Our Mission -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="mission" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Our Mission</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>The Legal Studies Academy is welcome to all students who have a deep interest in and curiosity about the law, law-related fields, and legal and ethical issues. The First Colonial Legal Studies Academy functions as a school-within-a-school to offer students the opportunity to not only embrace an academic curriculum that will fully prepare them for post-secondary education, but will also allow career exploration within the area of legal studies. Students enrolled in the Legal Studies Academy will receive a solid foundation in core subjects as well as practice and experience in a work-site learning component.<br>

          The Academy curriculum goes beyond the basic four-year high school requirement by infusing law-related units into the core subject areas of English, science, and social studies and by providing students with specialized coursework. The program of studies is extended through seminars and field trips on law-related subjects. In addition, they Academy offers students the opportunity to experience the reality of law careers by emphasizing active learning in criminal investigations and Mock Trials in our courtroom.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Our Mission -->
```

Anybody see anything wrong??

Comment: you have included jQuery lib 3 times, in header so as twice in footer, better remove from footer.

Comment: and bootstrap lib not included, possible file location is wrong, should check the browser console log for errors

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using the bootstrap js CDN then it is probably the easist option:

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

This will load all of the bootstrap JS functionality into your site. It will make it easier to use other bootstrap JS as well if you want to.

Otherwise, you can download the file locally and serve it like you are serving the bootstrap css.

Then, I would just build around this code 
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo
Which I think is where you got your current code.